# Find the favorite and analyse sequence questions in R

Tags: r

We have a daily meeting when participants nominate each other to speak. The first person is chosen randomly.
I have a dataframe that consists of names and the order of speech every day.
I have a `day1`, a `day2` ,a  `day3` , etc. in the columns. 
The data in the rows are numbers, meaning the order of speech on that particular day.
NA means that the person did not participate on that day.

```
Name    day1    day2   day3  day4 ...
Albert    1       3     1     ...
Josh      2       2     NA
Veronica  3       5     3
Tim       4       1     2
Stew      5       4     4
...
```

I want to create two analysis, first, I want to create a dataframe who has chosen who the most times. (I know that the result depends on if a participant was nominated before and therefore on that day that participant cannot be nominated again, I will handle it later, but for now this is enough)

It should look like this:

```
Name      Favorite    
Albert    Stew       
Josh      Veronica       
Veronica  Tim       
Tim       Stew
...
```

My questions (feel free to answer only one if you can): 
1. What code shall I use for it without having to manunally put the names in a different dataframe?
2. How shall I handle a tie, for example Josh chose Veronica and Tim first the same number of times? Later I want to visualise it and I have no idea how to handle ties.

I also would like to analyse the results to visualise strong connections.
Like to show that there are people who usually chose each other, etc.
Is there a good package that is specialised for these? Or how should I get to it?
I do not need DNA sequences, only this simple ones, but I have not found a suitable one yet.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So, according to your input dataset, on the first day Albert chose Josh, on the second, Stew and on the third, Tim?

Comment: Correct, he chose the one with one higher number than he is on that day.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not misunderstanding your problem, here is some code to get the number of occurences of who choose who as next speaker. I added a fourth day to have some count that is not 1. There are ties in the result, choosing the first couple of each group by speaker ('who') may be a solution :

```
df <- read.table(textConnection(
"Name,day1,day2,day3,day4
Albert,1,3,1,3
Josh,2,2,,2
Veronica,3,5,3,1
Tim,4,1,2,4
Stew,5,4,4,5"),header=TRUE,sep=",",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

purrr::map(colnames(df)[-1],
   function (x) {
        who <- df$Name[order(df[x],na.last=NA)]
        data.frame(who,lead(who),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
        }
) %>%
replyr::replyr_bind_rows() %>%
filter(!is.na(lead.who.)) %>%
group_by(who,lead.who.) %>% summarise(n=n()) %>%
arrange(who,desc(n))
```

Input:

```
      Name day1 day2 day3 day4
1   Albert    1    3    1    3
2     Josh    2    2   NA    2
3 Veronica    3    5    3    1
4      Tim    4    1    2    4
5     Stew    5    4    4    5
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   who [5]
   who      lead.who.     n
   <chr>    <chr>     <int>
 1 Albert   Tim           2
 2 Albert   Josh          1
 3 Albert   Stew          1
 4 Josh     Albert        2
 5 Josh     Veronica      1
 6 Stew     Veronica      1
 7 Tim      Stew          2
 8 Tim      Josh          1
 9 Tim      Veronica      1
10 Veronica Josh          1
11 Veronica Stew          1
12 Veronica Tim           1
```